# Godot 3: How to rotate a KinematicBody?

Tags: 3d, godot

I am a newbie in Godot and I am trying to make a 3d game, but I don't know how to **rotate** my player (who is a **KinematicBody**). Could somebody tell me how I should do this? I have tried so many different ways but I can't do it.

Comment: Please specify what you're trying to achieve. What have you tried?

Comment: I want when I press a s w d buttons to set the character's rotation to a specific value (e.g. **set** his rotation to 90 deg for right -90 for left..). I have tried the set_rotation method, rotation.y=.., vector3.rotated but I dont know if I did it wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using:

```
rotate_x(float angle) #angle is in radians
rotate_y(float angle)
rotate_z(float angle)
```

If you want to use degrees instead of radians, then just use:

```
rotate_x(deg2rad(float deg)) #deg is degrees
```