# How Can I Rotate character based on direction He is Moving in Godot 4.0 3D

Tags: 3d, rotation, godot, isometric, topdown

[image]

Is there a way to do it in code
For example :
Rotation.y = something

Comment: you could look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51818981/godot-3-how-to-rotate-a-kinematicbody?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rotation.y = atan2(velocity.x,velocity.z)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

var forward = -global_transform.basis.z
var angle = forward.angle_to(velocity)
rotate(Vector3.UP, angle)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).